# Filter a list based on value in an order?

Tags: c#, linq

What is the easiest way to filter a value with a null reference checking.Order should be like  "Active",
                "Reset",
                "Locked",
                "Suspended ",
                "Expired",
                "Disabled ",
                "Revoked"

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tempList = new List<string>
            {
                "Active",
                "Reset",
                "Locked",
                "Suspended ",
                "Expired",
                "Disabled ",
                "Revoked"
            };
            var list = new List<MyEntity>
            {
                new MyEntity() {MyValue = "Reset"},
                new MyEntity() {MyValue = "Locked"},
                new MyEntity() {MyValue = "Active"},
                new MyEntity() {MyValue = "Expired"}

            };

            var item =
                list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyValue));

        }
    }
    public class MyEntity
    {
        public string MyValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I need to do to get the filter the list based on value ...

Comment: So only pick an item with `MyValue` of "B" if no items in the list have a `MyValue` of "A"?  Also what is the exact type of `MyValue`?

Comment: var filtered = list.Sort().FirstOrDefault(); should do the trick

Comment: @juharr you are right

Comment: OK, and if none are A, B, C, or D then you want a `null` right?

Comment: I give a wrong example with A,B,C,D value it can be Sam,Paul,Jimmy and Jeff

Comment: OK, do you have a list of these values in the order you want to look for them?

Comment: just edited my question sorry for last example it was confusing

Comment: I think you are having an issue explaining what you want.  Please provide sample input and what you want as output.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Have edited it. Sorry for the confusion .yes you are right . My question was confusing

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to be the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do an `OrderBy` and if you want the preference to be Sam, then Paul, then Jimmy, then Jeff, and then `null` if none of those are present then you can do the following.

```
var listOfNames = new List<string> { "Sam", "Paul", "Jimmy", "Jeff" };
var item = list.Where(x => listOfNames.Contains(x.MyValue))
    .OrderyBy(x => listOfName.IndexOf(x.MyValue))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will first filter out anything that doesn't match the values you are interested it.  Then orders them by their position in the list and finally picks the first one or `null` if the filter resulted in no matches.

Also I'm just assuming `MyValue` is a `string` here, but if you need to you can do whatever conversion is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Actually var listOfNames = new List<string> { "Sam", "Paul", "Jimmy", "Jeff" }; list is a dynamic list and I don't have control over it

Comment: thanks for the inform . i got the problem btw i removed my answer because i think yours better.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury If this answer works for you, then could you please remove the `linq-to-entities` tag from your question because this is not (and definitely does not work in) Linq To Entities.